# Prestashop configuration.inc.php file /* Load all configuration keys */ problem

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to get my site uploaded to my host and have been getting this 
error when navigating to the domain url.

"Invalid loadConfiguration() SQL query!"

I believe the problem is the configuration.inc.php file the following part in particular

/* Load all configuration keys */
Configuration::loadConfiguration();

I am a newb and have no idea what this means. Any help please here is a link to the whole file code.

http://pastie.org/pastes/1320594/text

thx very much.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem; “Link to database cannot be established”.

As proposed here and elsewhere, I have changed the password in config/settings.inc.php manually back to the emailed password, but I still could not enter the site or the admin-page.

The solution for me was to change the password (also) of the database (mySql or php -I forgot) through my webhosting admin site (one.com).

PreHistory:
After I received a mail with a new password I got in to admin-page. As soon as I entered a new password in Tools/Preferences, I got kicked off with “Link to database cannot be established”.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to rewrite the config.php file but i cannot seem to find this file anywhere.. I have looked online everyone says a different name to the file.. So i don't think this code for the shop is user friendly..

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.
Edit the settings.inc.php inside the config folder.You can now see all the code in the file. Look for a line that is similar to the one below:

```
define('_DB_NAME_', 'your_db_name');
define('_DB_USER_', 'your_db_user');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'your_db_password');
```